# Using file replacements in order to replace service implementations

Tags: angular

Angular allows [file replacements](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements) via `fileReplacements` in the angular.json. One common use case is to replace the file environment.ts in order to target a certain build, e.g. with `ng build --configuration staging` and the following entry in `configurations` within the angular.json:

```
"staging": {
  ...,
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above works well and its use case is pretty clear.

However, let's assume the situation, that I want to replace services (and other files) via file replacements. An example for one specific service:

```
// service.interface.ts
export interface IService { doSomething(): void; }

// service.mock.ts
@Injectable()
export interface Service implements IService {
  doSomething(): void { throw Error(); }
}

// service.bar.ts
@Injectable()
export interface Service implements IService {
  doSomething(): void { // bar specific implementation }
}

// service.foo.ts
@Injectable()
export interface Service implements IService {
  doSomething(): void { // foo specific implementation }
}

// app.component.ts
import { Service } from './service.mock';
...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.service.doSomething();
  }
}
```

And `configurations` in the angular.json looks like:

```
"foo": {
  ...
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/app/service.mock.ts",
      "with": "src/app/service.foo.ts"
    }
  ]
},
"bar": {
  ...
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/app/service.mock.ts",
      "with": "src/app/service.bar.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

By using `ng build --configuration foo` or `ng build --configuration bar` I can now determine which implementation gets called via `this.service.doSomething();` in `AppComponent` - either the *foo* or the *bar* specific one. Long story short: this solution feels a bit odd. And keep in mind, that I might have a couple of services going this way, also routing and other files as well (resulting in a pretty long `fileReplacements`).

I was wondering: 1.) Are file replacements intended for this use case?; 2.) Are there any critical disadvantages or downsides?; and 3.) What are possible alternatives or rather what is the more Angular-like way (maybe something like dependency injection)?

Let me know, if further details are needed.

Comment: you could use https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider, it seems to be less "magical". you can check your environment and use the class you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of file replacement is that you won't have all the unused services bundled with the code. If it doesn't bother you that all of the unused services do get bundled then DI might be a good solution for you (Read on).

---

You could add a variable to your environment file(s) and then create a provider in your `NgModule`. [Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7dujcw)

You would create `x` number of services that all would extend a base service. This base service would then have some abstract data associated with it and may even some methods/properties that your children could use.

```js
// Some base class
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export abstract class Service {
  abstract name: string;
}

// Your foo service
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FooService extends Service {
  name = 'foo';
}

// Your bar service
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BarService extends Service {
  name = 'bar';
}
```

You would then create a provider in your module or even some other component that would provide `Service`. When you then inject it into your components/services/directives etc. the factory will get executed and decide which service to provide to the caller based on your environment variable that is setup.

```js
import { environment } from './environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Service,
      useFactory: (foo: FooService, bar: BarService) => {
        if (environment.somevar === 'mock') {
          throw new Error();
        } else if (environment.somevar === 'foo') {
          return foo;
        } else if (environment.somevar === 'bar') {
          return bar;
        }
      },
      deps: [FooService, BarService]
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Instead of doing DI injection on `FooService` or `BarService` we do it on the base service. Which when created will run the factory and return the proper class.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly myService: Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Using Service:', this.myService.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested your solution and it worked well.